# Conditions with ARRAY and JOptionPane

Tags: java, arrays, joptionpane

I want my program to display whether my array is equal to zero, greater than zero(POSITIVE) or less than zero(NEGATIVE), like this:

```
array[0] contains 0
array[1] contains 1
array[2] contans -2
```

then the output should be....

```
0 ZERO
1 POSITIVE
-2 NEGATIVE
```

something like that.
and here's my code:

```
        String display="";

        String size = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Your Prefered Size Of Your Array");
        int newsize = Integer.parseInt(size);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You Entered "+newsize+".");

        String array[] = new String[newsize];

        for (int a=0; a<array.length;a++)
        {
            array[a]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Value For Array["+a+"].");

        }



        for (int a=0;a<array.length;a++)
        {
            display=display+array[a]+"\n";

            if (array[a].compareTo(array[a])== 0)
            {
              String c = "ZERO";

            }
            else if (array[a].compareTo(array[a])< 0)
            {
                String c = "POSITIVE";

            }
            else if (array[a].compareTo(array[a])> 0)
            {
                String c = "NEGATIVE";

            }

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Arrays\n"+display);
```

the concrete problem is I don't know how to code this to display ZERO,POSITIVE,NEGATIVE strings with its corresponding array.

Comment: And do you have a concrete problem?

Answer (score 1):

Make some change to your second for loop, like,

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("Arrays\n");

    int intValue = 0;
    for (String a :  array) {
        intValue = Integer.valueOf(a);
        sb.append(intValue).append(' ');
        if (intValue == 0) {
            sb.append("ZERO");

        } else if (intValue > 0) {
            sb.append("POSITIVE");

        } else if (intValue < 0) {
            sb.append("NEGATIVE");

        }
        sb.append('\n');

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sb.toString());
    }
```

And then you will get an expected result:

[image]

Comment: a) no reason to call `Integer.valueOf(array[a])` over and over again in each branch. extract it to a variable at the top of the loop. b) no reason to use old school loops with counters, use `for(String a : array)`, that makes the code way simpler